# java array vowels alphabetical and couting

Tags: java, string

This is my code below for a piece of work I was working on. now I have to amend my program so it will ask for the names that needs sorted, and once the program is complete it needs to display the names in alphabetical order,, count how many characters each name has and how many vowels they have ??

could anyone possibly give me a hand ??

```
String[] StudentNames = new String[8];
StudentNames[0] = "Joel";
StudentNames[1] = "Amy";
StudentNames[2] = "Robert";
StudentNames[3] = "Conor";
StudentNames[4] = "Mark";
StudentNames[5] = "Stewart";
StudentNames[6] = "Jack";
StudentNames[7] = "James";
for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
    System.out.println(StudentNames[x]);
}
```

Comment: Don't post code as comment, it looses its formatting which makes it unreadable. Instead [edit] your question and include it there.

Comment: Also your current code doesn't seam to have any attempt to solve problems described in your question. If you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic you will learn that: "3. Questions asking for homework help must include a **summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem**, and a **description of the difficulty you are having** solving it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement Comparator:

```
public class YourClass implements Comparator<String>{

     public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

        String student1Name = ((String) o1); 
        String student2Name = ((String) o1); 

        int student1Vowels = countVowels(student1Name);
        int student2Vowels = countVowels(student2Name);

        if (student1Name == student2Name)
             return 0;
        if (student1Name > student2Name)
             return -1;
        if (student1Name < student2Name)
             return 1; 
    }   

    private int countVowels(String name){
       //return the vowels count
    }

}
```

This is an example which half suits to what you need, carry on with your requirements.

Comment: I need to also sort the names then so they are in alphabetical order, that each character in every name is counted and all the vowels in every name is counted....this is what am struggling with

Comment: So you will need to implement `Comparable`, I will update my answer by it

Comment: Sorry, I meant ot implement `Comparator`